# How to return to the current scene when iAd is clicked

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, iad

I am done with all the code for a sprite-Kit game, but iAd gave me lot of hard time. When iAd is clicked the game restarts again. How to fix this problem? I have the game with viewController , title Scene, levelOne Scene, level two scene. I read other related post but couldn't solve the issue. Thanks you.

viewController.h

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface RAViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *adView;
@end
```

viewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [adView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; // set to your screen dimensions
    [adView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.delegate = self;
[adView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; // set to your screen dimensions
[adView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

maybe delegate helps you. I didn't try this code, try it tell me if it works.

Comment: When I add adView.delegate = self; , it shows error "Assigning to 'id<ADVabberVuewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'viewController *const_strong

Comment: I have same problem on game center delegate